Convert float to integer representation
It's related with my previous question.
I want to map arbitrary float space into integer representation.
I have define the transformation, where $x'$ is integer representation, $x$ is real value like float32 or float64, and $b$ is the number of bit. $x$ and $x'$ are the vector.
$x'=\lfloor x \frac{\lfloor \frac{2^b - 1}{2} \rfloor}{\max\lvert x \rvert} \rfloor$
So, the baseline which is zero value is still same, where 0.0 in float space is 0 in integer space.
But, I'm not sure whether $\min(x')$ is always $-2^{b-1}$ and $\max(x')$ is always $2^{b-1} -1$. For any $x$.
How to proof it?
If there is counter, what is the right formula so the minimax of $x'$ is bounded like that?
Also, I'm considering about rounding error by IEEE 754 during conversion.
